# Sorting a JavaScript array of objects does not work

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:
The output of `console.log(myObject)` is:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
data: Array[19]
label: "Orange"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
data: Array[19]
label: "Black"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I need to sort the object by `label`

I've tried:

```
myObject.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return a.label - b.label;
});
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

**Q:** How can I sort the object by `label`?

Comment: Try `'Orange' - 'Black'` in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're preforming subtraction on a string, which doesn't make sense. Instead, use [`.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
myObject.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return a.label.localeCompare(b.label);
});
```

This method returns a negative number if `a` is less than `b`, a positive number if `a` is greater than `b` or `0` if equal.

Because the `.sort()` method expects a numeric value from the callback, this works perfectly.

You could also use comparison operators, though this isn't quite the same as `.localeCompare()`, which performs more sophisticated comparison of unicode characters rather than simple byte comparison.

```
myObject.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return a.label < b.label ? -1 : a.label > b.label ? 1 : 0;
});
```